# Sql Server Lag in same context?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, lag

I need to get the previous id from a table, but I want to limit that previous record to a given id which is id_sucursal (branch), because if I do not do this, the first row (of id_sucursal) will get the previous_id (the lag) from another sucursal.
I know I can order over id_sucursal and works fine but I want to keep it on the same id_sucursal context, this is the select statement, is so simple and does not needs more.

```
Select

    -- current id
    t.id,

    -- when i order everything is ok but on the first row 
    -- I get the id from another sucursal
    lag(id) OVER (ORDER BY t.id_sucursal) prev_id,

    -- here sucursal may be different
    t.id_sucursal

    From sucursal_info
```

It would be great to do something like:

```
Select

    t.id,

    lag(id) OVER (ORDER BY t.id_sucursal) (WHERE id_sucursal = t.id_sucursal) prev_id,

    --
    t.id_sucursal

    From sucursal_info
```

Of course there are more rows involved but I just brought needed ones to explain this.

Here is another example in smms:
[image]

Comment: It would be good if you give some sample data and expected output so it is easy for us to visualize. I guess you need `partition by` clause in `lag` but cant say for sure without seeing the sample data and expected output.

Comment: it is so simple, imagine you want to bring a set of lag rows from a table but limit those rows to the same context which in this case is id_sucursal for the lag and for the table that calls it.

Comment: I am still awaiting sample data and expected output. The screenshot hardly explains anything. [Please read how to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/5234334)

Comment: I have updated it with the example @Utsav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add **[`partition by`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)** clause in  **[`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)**.

```
....
lag(id) OVER (parition by id_sucursal ORDER BY id_sucursal) prev_id. 
.....
```

Also I don't see you setting alias for the table as `t` but you are referring to columns as `t.column_name`. Hence I removed it